# Blocking the export of an Outlook attachment if a file with the same name has already been exported

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

I created a code to export my files from outlook and send them to a folder (excluding the signatures). My new challenge is to make sure that when a file is downloaded, if a file with the same name already exists in the folder then it should not run the code.

I have thought of using such a code but have tried unsuccessfully to integrate it in my code at the bottom of this post:

```
Dim TestStr As String


  On Error Resume Next
    TestStr = Dir(FilePath)
  On Error GoTo 0

  If TestStr = "" Then
    FileExist = False
  Else
    FileExist = True
  End If
End Function
```

Here is my unsuccessful code so far which I can't seem to debug:

```
Public Sub Samenamesameformat(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim Atmt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim SavePath As String
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim sExt As String
Dim TestStr As String

SavePath = "C:\Users\Antoine.moyroud\Documents\Testexportadwords"
On Error Resume Next
    TestStr = Dir(SavePath)
  On Error GoTo 0
If TestStr = "" Then
        FileExist = False
      Else
        FileExist = True
      Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
    sExt = objFSO.GetExtensionName(Atmt)
    Select Case sExt
        Case "jpg", "png"
        Case Else
            Atmt.SaveAsFile SavePath & "\" & Atmt.DisplayName
    End Select
End If
Next
Set Atmt = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to export to a folder all attachments of an Outlook `Item` and thus need to make sure to export only those not already in the destination folder? or do you want to export the Outlook `Item` (which on its turn will bring along inside it all its attachments) and thus need to make sure to export it only if ALL (or ANY) of his attachments are not already in the destination folder?

Comment: Hi @user3598756 I think I need for my use case, the first scenario.
I get a lot of invoices forwarded to me by different departments and often the emails which forward the invoices share the same invoice. I would like to avoid having a script running unless it is necessary = a file I haven't already downloaded appears in my inbox.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Public Sub Samenamesameformat(Item As MailItem)
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim SavePath As String
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim sExt As String

    SavePath = "C:\Users\Antoine.moyroud\Documents\Testexportadwords"
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
        If Not objFSO.FileExists(SavePath & "\" & Atmt.FileName) Then
            sExt = objFSO.GetExtensionName(Atmt)
            Select Case sExt
                Case "jpg", "png"
                Case Else
                    Atmt.SaveAsFile SavePath & "\" & Atmt.DisplayName
            End Select
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I'm assuming your sub runs from inside Outlook, so that you don't need that `.Outlook` prefix for all Outlook Application Object Model variables

Comment: @AntoineMyrd: did you get through it?

Comment: @AntoineMyrd: it'd be nice to have feedback from you

Comment: sorry haven't had the chance to test it out yet, it's a side project so no rush but don't worry I'll tell you as soon as I've tested it! Thanks for your input! :)